# jqueryui: "TypeError: this.menu.element is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make an jquery-ui autocomplete widget out of an input created in JavaScript, like so:

```
function drawAutocomplete() {
    var fooBox = document.createElement("input");
    fooBox.id = "foobox";
    fooBox.name = "foobox";

    window.document.firstChild.appendChild(fooBox);

    $("#foobox").autocomplete({source: ["eenie", "meenie"]});
}
```

but I keep getting a

```
TypeError: this.menu.element is undefined
```

whenever I try to interact with the box, and no autocompletion alternatives are displayed.

Is it not possible to use dynamically created items in this way? What else could I have misunderstood?

Comment: Isn't the first child of document doctype or HTML tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element isn't added to the page properly:

```
window.document.firstChild.appendChild(fooBox);
```

Will try to append the data to the `doctype` (or `HTML`) tag.

Use

```
window.document.body.appendChild(fooBox);
```

So your dynamic code is fine (a strange blend of plain JS and jQuery), but should work fine once you add the `input` to the correct element. [*@phillip100*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962734/phillip100)'s answer shows you a nice way to optimize.

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(
function drawAutocomplete() {
    var fooBox = document.createElement("input");
    fooBox.id = "foobox";
    fooBox.name = "foobox";

    document.body.appendChild(fooBox);

    $("#foobox").autocomplete({source: ["eenie", "meenie"]});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I realize it is a strange blend - I'm new to this. How would it look in "proper" jquery?

Comment: Like the first example in @Phillip100's answer. That's nice and short and makes full use of jQuery's ability.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way using jQuery:

```
function drawAutocomplete() {
    // used body, since I'm not sure what element you're reffering to
    $('<input type="text" id="foobox" name="foobox">').appendTo('body')
    // don't search the DOM for '#foobox', use created element:
    .autocomplete({source: ["eenie", "meenie"]});
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Ldvkhv/)

---

Or using your code, wrap the `fooBox` HTML element into jQuery object.

```
function drawAutocomplete() {
   var fooBox = document.createElement("input");
   fooBox.id = "foobox";
   fooBox.name = "foobox";
   // used body, since I'm not sure what element you're reffering to
   document.body.appendChild(fooBox);
   $(fooBox).autocomplete({source: ["eenie", "meenie"]});
}
```

Either way, you don't have to search the DOM for `'#foobox'`, since you have already cached the element here: `var fooBox`(second example) or `$('<input ...>')`(first example).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9znn8uf1/1/)